# How would you say "a car manufactured by Toyota"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, prepositions, possessives

> I bought a car **manufactured by** Toyota.

How would you say "a car manufactured by Toyota"?

> I bought **Toyota's car**.

or

> I bought **a car of** Toyota.

or

> I bought **a car from** Toyota.

or

> I bought **a Toyota**.

or is there a better alternative?

Comment: "I bought a car made by Toyota".

Comment: @ekhumoro - While you ***could*** say that, no one does. It’s just, “I bought a Toyota.”

Comment: In English it is very common to call any object by the manufacturer’s name provided 1) the object is closely connected with the manufacturer, and 2) it is a major and identifying product by that manufacturer. Both these provisos are context-specific. Generally speaking, a Peugeot is a car; a Lenovo could be a computer or a smart phone; a Wilson is a tennis racket; and a Gucci is an item of clothing or an accessory. In specific contexts, a Peugeot could also be a bike or a pepper mill, and a Lenovo could be a chip.

Comment: When you refer to the manufacturer, you don't use "a", like in the title and first few sentences.  There is only one of the company and it doesn't need any article.  "A Toyota" would refer to a vehicle made by Toyota.

Comment: Ironically, on Travel Stack Exchange, there's a question about what "A Toyota" is: [What class of vehicle is commonly called "a Toyota" in Dudhu Chak/Eastern Pakistan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44066/what-class-of-vehicle-is-commonly-called-a-toyota-in-dudhu-chak-eastern-pakist)

Comment: This question shows thought and research, as such it's +1 from me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Side comment: If you ask for a Bic in the US (and UK iirc), you will get a lighter. If you ask for a Bic in Belgium; you will get a ballpoint pen. We still very much use bic lighters, but the eponymous name was attached to the pens before the lighters became popular enough.

Answer (score 8):

As Janus Bahs Jacquet points out, it's common to call a product by the manufacturer's name when it's closely identified with the manufacturer.

Thus you can say "I bought a Toyota."

If you say "I bought a car manufactured by Toyota" you could mean that you bought a Lexus, which is also manufactured by Toyota.

If you say "I bought a car "from Toyota," you imply that Toyota is the seller of the car, which it may or may not be.  You may have bought the car second-hand or from a dealer rather than directly from the manufacturer.

"Toyota's car" and "a car of Toyota" are both odd-sounding and not idiomatic.  However, it's possible to say "I like Toyota's cars", meaning that you like the  various models and brands of cars that Toyota produces.  You might say "I like GM's cars--the Corvette and the Volt and even the SUV's."

Comment: Even in your examples at the end, I still find a simple plural (“I like Toyotas”) or using the brand name as a noun adjunct (“I like GM cars”) more natural. And of course, if you say you bought Toyota’s car, you might just be bragging that you bought a car that previously belonged to [Mr Toyota himself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiichiro_Toyoda).